# Trying to understand how static is working in this case

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am looking at some code that a coworker wrote and what I expected to happen isn't. Here is the code:

```
public class SingletonClass
{
    private static readonly SingletonClass _instance = new SingletonClass();

    public static SingletonClass Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    } 

    private SingletonClass()
    {
        //non static properties are set here
        this.connectionString = "bla"
        this.created = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

In another class, I would have expected to be able to do:

```
private SingletonClass sc = SingletonClass.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance;
```

and it reference the same Instance of that class. What happens is I can only have one `.Instance`. Something that I did not expect. If the `Instance` property returns a `SingletonClass` class, why can't I call the `Instance` property on that returned class and so on and so on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If the Instance property returns a SingletonClass class, why can't I call the Instance property on that returned class and so on and so on?

Because you can only access `.Instance` via the `SingletonClass` *type*, not via an instance of that type.

Since `Instance` is static, you must access it via the type:

```
SingletonInstance inst = SingletonInstance.Instance; // Access via type

// This fails, because you're accessing it via an instance
// inst.Instance
```

When you try to chain these, you're effectively doing:

```
SingletonInstance temp = SingletonInstance.Instance; // Access via type

// ***** BAD CODE BELOW ****
// This fails at compile time, since you're trying to access via an instance
SingletonInstance temp2 = temp.Instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code  you are returning an instance of `SingletonClass` via the Instance which is an static of type Singleton

so it wont allow you to do this `SingletonClass.Instance.Instance` because the `SingletonClass.Instance` is returning an instance of `SingletonClass`

All it doing is saving you from doing this `SingletonClass _instance = new SingletonClass();`
 in to this `SingletonClass.Instance.Instance`